# Express SSL authentication functionality missing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typescript, ssl

I am trying to use SSL authentication with Express as discussed in http://intown.biz/2016/11/22/node-client-auth/.

We are using TypeScript for our server code (in addition to client Angular code) for the strong typing benefit.
We are using Express 4.14.1, @types/express": "^4.0.36"

The link above (as is the case with most server side NodeJS) is JavaScript not TypeScript. There is a chunk of code in the link that looks like the following:

```js
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   if (!req.client.authorized) {
       return res.status(401).send('User is not authorized');
   }
   #examine the cert itself, and even validate based on that!
   var cert = req.socket.getPeerCertificate();
   if (cert.subject) {
       console.log(cert.subject.CN);
   }
   next();
});
```

The application discussed in the link works (he has a link to download the project).

My problem: The latest types (4.0.36) don’t seem to have **req.client** or **req.socket.getPeerCertificate()**. They are not available in my TypeScript code (we do have Express imported/required). Also, I tried
passing the TypeScript Request object into a plain JavaScript function and **req.client** and **req.socket.getPeerCertificate()** are still undefined. They just 
aren't there.

Note: We do have Passport initialized also. We are using that to authenticate our web application (client and internal REST API) but we have an 
external/separate REST API that we wish to secure with SSL certificates. I doubt that having Passport plugged in would cause the the **req.client** and **req.socket.getPeerCertificate()** features to disappear?

Can anyone tell me why I am not seeing req.client or req.socket.getPeerCertificate() in my Express code? Did they get replaced with something?

Any help/ acknowledgements with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure about `req.client`, but `req.socket` should be defined because Express `req` objects are "enhanced versions" of the built-in `http.ClientRequest`, which has a [`.socket`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_socket) property. In case of TLS connections, this is an instance of [`tls.TLSSocket`](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_class_tls_tlssocket), which has [`.authorized`](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tlssocket_authorized) and [`.getPeerCertificate`](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tlssocket_getpeercertificate_detailed) properties.

Comment: Oh, `req.client` is the same as `req.socket` ([here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/ae4fde8bc883686def5badfb324236320669e8f4/lib/_http_incoming.js#L71)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[robertklep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893780/robertklep) was a huge help.

For TypeScript, I need to import `tls.TLSSocket` to get the typing all worked out,
and cast `req.socket` as `TLSSocket`:

```
((req.socket) as TLSSocket).authorized
((req.socket) as TLSSocket).getPeerCertificate().
```

In regular old JavaScript it got a little complicated. For my develop environment I am creating an httpServer (`http.createServer`). In my production environment I am creating an httpsServer (`https.createServer`). So with JavaScript `req.client` and `req.socket.getPeerCertificate()` weren't defined if I wasn't working in my production environment because the server hadn't been created with `https.createServer`.

Thanks robertklep!